# Troubled trying to convert a column data type in pgAdmin from varchar to integer (SQL state: 22P02)

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I am simply trying to convert a column with `character varying` data type to `integer` by run this bit of Postgres script:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl.test ALTER COLUMN "XX" TYPE integer USING ("XX"::integer);
```

and I get this error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "XX" SQL state: 22P02

Can someone help me to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: Find your bad values with `select "XX" from tbl.test where "XX" !~ '^-{0,1}\d+$';`

Comment: Thanks mate. Problem solved! If you add it as answer I will accept it. Plus, will be good to explain what `!~ '^-{0,1}\d+$'` does for clarity.

Comment: That bit of code with the "USING" is handy, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error you get it looks like you have some values in `XX` that cannot be converted to an `integer`.  You will need to correct those values before issuing the `alter table`.

Find your incorrect values with this query:

```
select "XX" from tbl.test where "XX" !~ '^-{0,1}\d+$';
```

The `!~` is the `NOT` regex match.  The regex anchors to the beginning of the value with `^`, accounts for an optional minus sign with `-{0,1}`, which matches zero or one hyphen character, and then insures that the remaining characters to the end of the value are all digits with `\d+$`.

Any values of `XX` that fail to match this pattern will be retrieved, and you can figure out how to deal with them either by updating the table or modifying the `using` part of your `alter table`.